# Issue with shell login

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, root, kvm

There is this strange thing I am seeing.
when ever i try to ssh into a machine with root user, I get logged in as "airoot" but the same does not happen for any other user.

```
    [root@ftc-unem32-22s27 onestopsolution]# ssh root@10.33.22.1
    Last login: Tue Jun  3 08:19:17 2014 from 10.32.22.27
    [airoot@node0fs ~]#
```

This happens for root user but for another user say User1234 it doesn't

```
    [root@ftc-unem32-22s27 onestopsolution]# ssh User1234@10.33.22.1
    User1234@10.33.22.1's password:
    Last login: Tue Jun  3 08:19:09 2014 from 10.32.22.27
    [User1234@node0fs ~]$
```

Comment: have you checked if the prompt is just different for the root user - e.g. if you do "whoami" after ssh'ing as root does it show airoot or root.

Comment: yes its different. It shows airoot.

Comment: Check the .bashrc of root (must be in `/.bashrc`, there must be some `su - airoot` around.

Comment: Nothing in /root/.bashrc, any place else I should look into.

Comment: Check what is the log in path for root with `awk -F: '/^root:/{print $6}' /etc/passwd`. It can also be in `/etc/profile`. Just do some search of `airoot` around these files. Also, check `who am i`

Comment: What does `id root` say on that machine? What about `id airoot`?